# Find {E1,..En} (E1+E2+..En=N, N is given) with the following property that E1* E2*..En is Maximum

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Given the number N, write a program that computes the numbers E1, E2, ...En with the following properties:

1) N = E1 + E2 + ... + En;
2) E1 * E2 * ... En is maximum.
3) E1..En, are integers. No negative values :)

How would you do that ? I have a solution based on [divide et impera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_et_impera) but i want to check if is optimal.

```
Example: N=10

5,5        S=10,P=25
3,2,3,2    S=10,P=36
```

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed? -10, -10, 30 sum up to 10 and their product is 3000.

Comment: what should '2) E1 * E2 * ... En is maximum.' be equal to

Comment: @Benoit Sorry, no negative values. But nice try :)

Comment: @Rohit the product is maxim. See example.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth optimal as lower complexity is better.

Comment: This would be a nice question on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: You haven't specified integers or real numbers.  If it's real numbers, the solution is E1=E2=...=En=N/n.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Only integers.

Comment: This is a project Euler problem. The latest in fact, PE374. As such, the poster is trying to get us to do his work, something that PE explicitly asks us not to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for an algorithm, mathematic intuition can do it on its own:

#### Step 1: prove that a result set with numbers higher than 3 is at most as good as a result set with only 3's and 2's

Given any number *x* in your result set, one might consider whether it would be better to divide it into two numbers.

The sum should still be *x*.

- When *x* is even, The maximum for *t* (*x* - *t*) is reached when *t* = *x*/2 , and except for the special case *x* = 2, then it is greater than *x*, and for the special case *x* = 4, equal to x (see note 1).
- When *x* is odd, The maximum for *t* (*x* - *t*) is reached when *t* = (*x* ± 1)/2.

What does this show? Only that you should only have 3's and 2's in your final set, because otherwise it is suboptimal (or equivalent to an optimal set).

#### Step 2: you should have as many 3's as possible

Now, as 3² > 2³, you should have as many 3's as possible as long as the remainder is not 1.

Conclusion: for every N >= 3:

- If N = 0 mod 3, then the result set is only 3's
- If N = 1 mod 3, then the result set has one pair of 2's (or a 4) and the rest is 3's
- If N = 2 mod 3, then the result set has one 2 and the rest is 3's

Please correct this post. The times when I was writing well-structured mathematical proofs is far away...

Note 1: (2,4) is the only pair of distinct integers such that x^y = y^x. You can prove that with:

```
x^y = y^x
y ln(x) = x ln(y)
ln(x)/x = ln(y) / y
```

and the function `ln(t)/t` is strictly decreasing after its global maximum, reached between 2 and 3, so if you want two distinct integers such that `ln(x)/x = ln(y)/y`, one of them must be lower or equal to 2. From that you can infer that only (2,4) works

Comment: If a mathematical demonstration exists this is it :). I got the same result by coding. Yes, 3 is the gold length for this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but might help.

First off note that if you fix n, and two of the terms E_i and E_j differ by more than one (for example 3 and 8), then you can do better by "equalizing" them as much as possible, i.e., if the number p = E_i + E_j is even, you do better both terms by p/2. If p is odd, you do better by replacing them with p/2 and p/2+1 (where / is integer division).

That said, then if you knew what the optimal number of terms, n, was, you'd be done: let all E_i's equal N/n and N/n+1 (again integer division), so that their sum is still N (this is now a straightforward problem).

So the question now is what is the optimal n. Suppose for the moment that you are allowed to use real numbers. Then the solution would be N/n for each term and you could write the product as (N/n)^n. If you differentiate this with respect to n and find its root you find that n should be equal to N/e (where e is the Neper number, also known as Euler's number, e = 2.71828....). Therefore, I'd look for a solution where either n = floor(N/e) or n = floor(N/e)+1, and then choose all the E_i's equal to either N/n or N/n+1, as above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just saw Benoit's solution, which is better than mine. In fact my solution will lead to the same result, because N/n = N/floor(N/e) is either 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

The Online Encycolpedia of Integer Sequences gives a [recurrence relation](http://oeis.org/A000792) for the solution to this problem.

I'll leave it up to someone else to compare complexities. Not sure I can figure out the complexity of OP's method.

Comment: D'ohhhh.  Another test failed by not reading the question properly.